# Nodejs Server calling another js file at current time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to call my scrappers at a current time.

For instance:

Lets say I want to run the scrappers at 09.00.00

I have lots of scrappers to run. I just found a method to do that but I think it can miss the time.

```
setInterval(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    if(hours === 9 && minutes === 00){
        how to run them?
    }
},60000);
```

This will check the time every 60 seconds. But I do not know it will work good or not.

How can I run them and Is there another way to run them at 09.00 that will work better ?

Comment: use child processes ? https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: A little bit of other knowledge, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron Cron jobs are tasks that run at some sort of predefined interval; So in the past I've used node modules that have "cron" styled tasks. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to continue to develop your own code, think about how you would prevent it missing a time (well, if the time is greater than 9!  easy! ... but then it will run every 60 seconds, well make a counter to make sure it doesn't run more than once a day `if(completed<1)`! But then you run into how to reset `completed` on the next day (well create a variable to track when you last reset the counter...)

Comment: @CodyG. Cron seems good. thx man

Comment: @WilomGfx it can be a solution too. Thx man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule. It has cron like operation even on Windows. Do note however that the scheduled event will only fire if your node.js script is running.

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
var runScrapper = schedule.scheduleJob('* 9 * * *', function(){
     //Run scrapper here
});
```

To get the package simply execute the following in your project directory.

```
 npm install node-schedule --save
```

Use the follow to stop the interval when desired.

```
runScrapper.cancel();
```

Comment: is it using my local time or any other ?

Comment: It uses your machines local time.